# Has Facebook quietly retired public access to daily_active_users field on the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Typically, the Graph API Application object contains the following public fields: `daily_active_users`,     `weekly_active_users`, and `monthly_active_users` (see [Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/).)

I have been unable to access these using FQL or Facebook's [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2439131959%3Ffields%3Dweekly_active_users%2Cdaily_active_users%2Cmonthly_active_users%2Clogo_url%2Cid) for a couple of days.

Furthermore, I note that AppData.com's chart of [daily activity](http://www.appdata.com/gainers/today) seems to be broken. I've contacted them to ask what their experience has been.)

Despite this, the fields are still in the documentation and available as part of the ([new! improved!](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/30/updates-to-the-graph-api/))  Graph Explorer which might lead one to think that they're still supported.

1. Has anyone seen any communication from Facebook around this issue?
2. Is this a very bad sign?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem that begun around yesterday or the day before.
AppData seems to duplicate the numbers of the previous days at the moment.

FQL seems to work somehow: [(Click this for Zynga Poker)](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20metric,%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id=2389801228%20AND%20metric=%27application_active_users%27%20AND%20end_time=end_time_date%28%272011-09-03%27%29%20AND%20period=period%28%27month%27%29&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBANF3NjZCIUcFnZBfb2F1lpCZB305IpaBlNzhiHqCqs5klyrGr4Tw5Seb27FfBwzViNQ3BzGCf87MqJQnWhKBIbZB9QlOnZAsl5lWwSDSi)

But this not a good solution - I also need the Graph API back.

Comment: I stand corrected - this method brings all the correct numbers up to 2012-08-27. Starting 28/8 it returns no data. Back to point 0. :(

Comment: Have just heard from Eric Moore at AppData: "Facebook is currently experiencing data reporting delays for MAU and DAU numbers. Facebook is working to resolve this issue and we will post status updates on http://appdata.com/"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/448404715204675 (apparently *this* is where one should go...)